# Error installing Workflow Manager

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, workflow-manager-1.x

While installing workflow Manager to use it with SharePoint 2013, I'm getting this error:

```
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The api-version in the query string is not supported. Either remove it from the Uri or use one of '2012-03'..TrackingId:0aef4968-6974-41db-bf43-fecd4fda4a38_GDS-SP2013-VM,TimeStamp:5/15/2014 1:27:51 PM ---> System.ArgumentException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The api-version in the query string is not supported. Either remove it from the Uri or use one of '2012-03'..TrackingId:0aef4968-6974-41db-bf43-fecd4fda4a38_GDS-SP2013-VM,TimeStamp:5/15/2014 1:27:51 PM ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.GetAsyncResult`1.EndGetResponse(GetAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Did anyone ever get this problem? I'm trying to investigate the issue but I can't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happens to you, delete all the workflow manager databases and re-install again. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a service bus version issue.
Install the correct one using Web Platform Installer.

At this moment I run Workflow Manager Refresh 1.0 and servicebus 1.0 CU.